# Osquery SQL - searching for executables

Tags: sql, osquery

I need some help. What syntax do I use to search for executables using osquery?
For example, I am looking for winword.exe, excel.exe. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please, show what did you try so far and what was the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Generally, `osquery` is not used to exhaustively search disk. This kind of action tends to be very slow and failure prone.

More common is to use osquery to examine the installed programs.

This can be done with the [`programs` table](https://osquery.io/schema/4.6.0/#programs). Though this will not find the exe directly,

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand what you're trying to achieve in this, but you can also search for currently running processes and filter out all of the distinct executables that are running right now. You won't get all of the pids from this, but atleast a list of all of the EXEs that are running right now

```
SELECT count(*) count, pid, name, state, root, on_disk, total_size from processes where name like '%exe' group by name;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select * from yara where path LIKE '/path/%/%' and sigrule = 'rule exeSearch { condition: uint16(0) == 0x5A4D }';
```